# Insert values in mysql

Tags: python

In the following example, I have managed to print the sql values those I will like to insert in mysql table.
How do I actually execute the statement?

```
import re
import MySQLdb

s = "Jul 15 12:12:51 whitelist logger: 1|999999999999|id:d9faff7c-4016-4343-b494-37028763bb66 submit date:1307130919 done date:1307130919 stat:DELIVRD err:0|L_VB3_NM_K_P|1373687445|vivnel2|L_VB3_GH_K_P|promo_camp1-bd153424349bc647|1"

logger_re = re.compile(
"logger: ([^ ]+)\
 submit date:(\d+)\
 done date:(\d+)\
 stat:(.+)\
 err:(.+)$")

myvalues = logger_re.search(s).groups()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="passwd", # your password
                      db="test") # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the query you need
cur = db.cursor() 

# cur.execute(insert into test.weblogs (output of myvalues))
```

The values needs to be extracted from a text file. Typically /var/log/messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should help

after reading your question, it's hard to say what exactly is your problem (formatting the query, commit process?)

```
try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable (id,somerow) VALUES (%s, %s)" % ("someid", "somerow"))
    db.commit()
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print e[0], e[1]
    db.rollback()
```